# 4*4 matrix type for opengl shader?

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

what type should I best use to pass in a transformation matrix into my vertex shader in opengl and how do i convert my vec3 position to a vec4 with a 1 in the fourth row for the multiplication most efficiently?
I want it to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

`mat4` is the type to pass a 4x4 floating point matrix to a GLSL shader program. You update it with the [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) call.

See this question: [Shader position vec4 or vec3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935203/shader-position-vec4-or-vec3) for a discussion of vec3 vs vec4 position data. It likely does not matter however, the vertex stage in the pipeline is rarely a bottleneck in rendering.