# Can I upload a vec3 value to vec4 uniforms?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've just read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18940430/5614012?stw=2) and its comments and have some related questions:

- Does this rule apply to uniform variables too?
- Can I call glUniform3fv for vec4 uniform and expect the W component to be 1.0, etc.?
- Where does the OpenGL spec mention about this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these rules do not apply to uniforms. Consequently, you are not allowed to call `glUniform3fv` on a `vec4`.

The [Spec states in Section 7.6.1](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf):

> For all [...] uniform types loadable with Uniform* commands, the command
>   used must match the size and type of the uniform, as declared in the shader, and
>   no type conversions are done.

Answer (score 4):

The specs in (7.6. UNIFORMVARIABLES) say that the `Uniform*` would result in `INVALID_OPERATION` error if:

> the size indicated in the name of the `Uniform*` command used does not match the size of the uniform declared in the shader,

or

> the component type and count indicated in the name of the `Uniform*` command used does not match the type of the uniform declared in the shader, where a boolean uniform component type is considered to match any of the `Uniform*i{v}`, `Uniform*ui{v}`, or `Uniform*f{v}` commands.

And testing to call `glUniform3f` for a `vec4` uniform will indeed result in a `INVALID_OPERATION` error.