# OpenGL VBO locations memory consumption

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

My Opengl App uses this layout in vertex shader:

```
layout(location=0) in vec4 inVertex_ID; // 4*4 = 16 bytes
layout(location=1) in vec4 inUV_Color_Mode; // 4*4 = 16 bytes, total 32 bytes
```

Actually, 4th component of location 0 (ID) and color/mode should be 32 bit uint numbers, and I do some neckbreaking stuff both on CPU and in shader to handle it.

I only use 2 locations of vec4, since I expected, that using more locations, with unused components, would mean to waste GPU memory.

I found this answer, which uses just 1 location
[Shader position vec4 or vec3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935203/shader-position-vec4-or-vec3)
and suggests, that using vec3, instead of vec4 should save memory, but it's not clear to me, whether it's CPU or GPU one.

Also, I guess the problem could be solvable by using "component" qualifier, ( e.g. `layout(location = 0, component = 2)` ) but it's core only from OpenGL 4.4 and I target towards 3.2.

So my question is, if this layout will use more GPU memory, than my previous one, or not.

```
layout(location=0) in vec3 inVertex; // 3*4 = 12 bytes
layout(location=1) in uvec3 inID_Color_Mode; // 3*4 = 12 bytes
layout(location=2) in vec2 inUV;  // 2*4 = 8 bytes; total 32 bytes
```

Comment: It's not the shader layout that uses memory, it's the data you upload to your buffers. If you upload the same data in both cases (or at least the same amount of data), then both layouts will use the same memory. What the other post means is that when you leave away the (unused) w-component **in the VBO** and thus adjust your layout, you will save memory.

Comment: Thanks BDL, that's great news. So I guess, glBufferData "size" parameter should govern this. I was in impression, that location size (vec4) + using glEnableVertexAttribArray for more locations, also means some on-the-fly GPU memory alignment of CPU data during upload, and thus GPU memory waste.

Comment: Without knowing how this is exactly implemented in the driver: At the point where you upload data, the layout is unknown. Even afterwards, you can use the same buffer with different layouts at the same time. You can even access it as SSBO in byte form. I don't think that there is any alignment copying going on, but there might be driver/vendor dependent differences.